# ASPX - How to read Lines from a Txt file then store text within a string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Im trying to read a text file using aspx then store whatever line it read in a string ive looked online and cant seem to find a straightforward tutorial can some one help me thank you.

Comment: are you trying to read data from a file on the server side (via c# or vb in asp.net) or are you trying to read data from a file on the client side (via javascript) ?

Comment: read data from the server im coding it i need to read a text file from the same directory as the aspx file

Answer (score 1):

once the file is on the server in a known location you just need to do the following:

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/upload/MyTextFile.txt"));
string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
```

Comment: how about reading line one then line two woukd this be any harder

Answer (score 1):

```
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
            string sLine="";
            List<string> lstText = new List<string>();

            while (sLine != null)
            {
                // Line by line read and add it to your List
                sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (sLine != null)
                    lstText.Add(sLine);
            }
                        objReader.Close();

            foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
                Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Please follow below links

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306777

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx